# plot xtable or save it as image

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, xtable

I want to use `xtable` layouts in my `powerpoint` presentations and I need a way to directly convert a `data.frame` into a picture or plot of an `xtable` such as the ones displayed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf).

The ideal solution would give me a `ggplot` object as I have the most flexibility from there, but I can work with another output as long as I can see a `xtable` in a pic (raster or vector) or plot window.

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9298765/680068

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318578/680068

Comment: Great thanks, please don't mark as duplicate, I'll compile the relevant info and will post an easy solution here.

Comment: Just pointing to relevant posts, not closing. If you think this is a dupe, then please close and post your answer on the target.

Comment: Actually first link require at least `yap` and `dvipng` that I cannot install. Second solution uses `ggplot2` and `gridExtra` and can be summarized as `ggplot() + annotation_custom(tableGrob(head(iris))) + theme_void()` and `tableGrob` has a `theme` parameter that allows enough flexibility to reproduce something close to `xtable`. See this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html .

Comment: Why as an image? If you do want as a real table in pptx, you can use flextable package: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/examples.html#xtable-objects

Comment: I'll take a look as it seems very interesting! But `officer` creates or edits the powerpoint code, it doesn't edit an open presentation on the fly. I've built a package that does that (FYI, though not intended for public consumption: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/ppt)  and I intend to copy my tables at specific positions using this package, though pasting powerpoint tables looking just the same would be amazing.

Comment: OK, you could have a look at package R2PPT. Use webshot to get a screen shot of xtable and then use R2PPT to add the content in your open pptx file.

Comment: great thanks, I didn't know `webshot` and was thinking of developing my own

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2` and `grid.extra` we can achieve decently looking tables:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
ggplot() + annotation_custom(tableGrob(head(iris))) + theme_void()
```

`tableGrob` has a theme parameter that allows enough flexibility to reproduce something close to `xtable`. see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html).

Here's a convenient function to do a bit more, you'll need packages `grid` and `gtable` :

```
table_plot <- function(x,
                       theme_fun= gridExtra::ttheme_minimal,
                       base_size = 12,
                       base_colour = "black",
                       base_family = "",
                       parse = FALSE,
                       padding = unit(c(4, 4), "mm"),
                       col = base_colour,
                       lwd=1,
                       lty=1
                       ){
  g <- gridExtra::tableGrob(x,
    theme = theme_fun(base_size, base_colour, base_family, parse, padding))
  separators <- replicate(ncol(g) - 2,
                          grid::segmentsGrob(x1 = unit(0, "npc"), gp=gpar(col=col,lwd=lwd,lty=lty)),
                          simplify=FALSE)
  g <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(g, grobs = separators,
                               t = 2, b = nrow(g), l = seq_len(ncol(g)-2)+2)
  ggplot2::ggplot() + ggplot2::annotation_custom(g) + ggplot2::theme_void()
}
```

simple example:

```
table_plot(head(iris))
```

complicated example :

```
iris2 <- setNames(head(iris)[1:3],c("alpha*integral(xdx,a,infinity)", "this text\nis high", 'alpha/beta'))
table_plot(iris2,
           base_size=10,
           base_colour="darkred",
           base_family = "serif",
           parse=TRUE,
           theme=ttheme_default,
           lwd=3,
           lty=2,
           col="darkblue")
```